# LINUX - Tensorflow 2.1.0: ERROR: could not a find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, pip, installation

I am trying to install tensorflow on my linux machine, but I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

The command I'm running is:

```
$ pip install tensorflow
```

I have also tried

```
$ python3 -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-2.1.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl
```

which comes from the Tensorflow site, which gives me the error:

```
ERROR: tensorflow_gpu-2.1.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I have been googling this issue for hours to no avail.
I even tried to install Anaconda, but something stood out to me when I did. I got this warning:

```
(my virtual environment)$ bash ~/Downloads/Anaconda3-2019.10-Linux-x86_64.sh
WARNING:
    Your operating system appears not to be 64-bit, but you are trying to
    install a 64-bit version of Anaconda3.
    Are sure you want to continue the installation? [yes|no]
```

this was weird to me because I thought I was running 64-bit architecture, bcause I have:

```
(my virtual environment)$ uname -a
Linux (MACHINE) 4.9.140-tegra #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Dec 9 22:52:02 PST 2019 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

is that not 64-bit? 
My pip version is also: `pip 20.0.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip (python 3.6)`

Every solution I've tried hasn't worked. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Maybe this processor architecture is not supported?

Comment: You have a 64bit ARM processor, but `tensorflow` is precompiled for 64bit x86 architecture. AFAIK there are no prebuilt wheels for `tensorflow>=2.0` out there, not even nvidia has prepared some for their Jetson boards. You can always build it from source though, there are lots of tutorials out there for that.

Comment: Looks like I was wrong and [nvidia does offer prebuilt wheels after all](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/install-tf-jetson-platform/index.html#install), so if you run Python 3.6 on a Jetson board, you're in luck - `pip3 install --pre --extra-index-url https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/redist/jp/v43 tensorflow` should do it.